# how to run a groovy method from gradle task?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am using

Gradle version 2.14

Groovy version 2.4.4

JVM:          1.8.0_121

I want to run a specific groovy method from a groovy class. How do I make associations with a groovy class from a gradle task ?

my task looks somewhat like this

```
task someTask << { 
  // Do something
  // Call method, which returns a java.io.File
  // Do something else
}
```

and my groovy class/method

```
File getSomeFile(String parameter) {
  // Do something
  // return an instance of java.io.File or maybe null, depending
}
```

So how do I call the method which takes a parameter and returns java.io.File ?

- (hope this is not a dublicate, i looked around, not finding exactly what I need)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Foo {
        void bar() { println 'bar'; }
    }
task someTask {
    doLast {
        new Foo().bar(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: The << operator is deprecated in gradle 3, you may want to avoid recommending it to Gradle beginners.

Comment: http://mrhaki.blogspot.se/2016/11/gradle-goodness-replacing-operator-for.html

task someTask {
    doLast{
          new Foo().bar(); 
    }
}

Comment: i like mr. haki. yes, that is preferred. but since we are defining the task, perhaps just: task someTask { new Foo().bar(); } is ok?

Comment: They have different results. The `<<` operator is/was syntactical sugar for `.doLast` construct. Code written in a `<<` closure is executed in the execution stage. The code you wrote here will instead be executed in the configuration stage, so it is not equivalent to the example in the question. Mr Haki explains this in more depth in his blog entry.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle scripts ARE Groovy scripts, just do it as in any other Groovy script. Just make sure your class is in the classpath, e. g. by depending on the library that includes the file in `builscript { dependencies {} }`, or by stuffing the file into the `buildSrc` project of your Gradle project.